# Animating views before destruction in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

There is currently no way to delay view destruction in Ember.
This presents a problem when you want to animate the view before destroying it.

So, I currently have this extremely ugly workaround:

```
willDestroyElement: ->
  $clone = @$().clone().addClass "animate-destruction"
  @$().parents(':first').prepend $clone
  setTimeout ->
    $clone.off().remove()
  , 350
```

Note: animation is done in the `.animate-destruction` class in css.

I know my method is bad, so I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a better way.

Comment: Related: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/animation-support-in-ember-1-1/1977

Answer (score 1):

This is just an spontaneous idea from my side:

This is the implementation of destroyElement in Ember.View ([Link to Source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1634)):

```
 destroyElement: function() {
    return this.currentState.destroyElement(this);
  },
```

You could try to override this method to do your animation:

```
destroyElement: function() {
    var completeCallback = function(){
        return this.currentState.destroyElement(this);
    }
    this.$().fadeOut(completeCallback); //or whatever animation
},
```

Comment: This was actually my first thought, until I tried it.  I discovered it doesn't work because after reading view destruction code (mainly the `willDestroy` callback) I discovered this:

`destroyElement` is rarely called on a view to destroy the actual DOM element, as usually it is a parent view's element that is removed, and `destroyElement` is called on children only for callbacks sake (the DOM element was actually removed by the parent). Your view will usually be a child view.

There are also other reasons, like when using `{{outlet}}`, the new view replaces it in anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Ember.Route.extend({
actions: {
willTransition: function(transition) {
        $.each(Ember.View.views, function(index, value) {
            var popUpView = value.get('classNames').find(function(item) {
                return item == '[nameofyourclass]';
            });
            if(!Em.isEmpty(popUpView) && value.get('visible')) {
                value.set('visible', false);
                value.get('controller').set('previousTransition', transition);
                transition.abort();
            }
        });
        return true;
},
 }
    });

Ember.View.extend({
classNames: ['nameofyourclass'],
classNameBindings: ['visible:element-visible'],

visible: false,

didInsertElement: function() {
    var t = this,
            controller = this.get('controller');
    this.$()
    .on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function() {
        if(!t.get('visible')) {
            var previousTransition = controller.get('previousTransition');
            if(!Em.isEmpty(previousTransition)) {
                controller.set('previousTransition', null);
                previousTransition.retry();
            } else { // fallback
                controller.transitionToRoute('index');
            }
        }
    });
    Em.run.next(this, function() {
        this.set('visible', true);
    });
},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method for handling pre-destroy animation is using `Em.Evented`. Have the view listen for an event that is called in the method or action that will start destruction of the view and delay the destruction until the method triggered by the event is complete (using the run loop). For example:

```
SomeView = Em.View.extend({

  _listen: function() {
    this.get('controller').on('closeChildView', this, this.hide);
  }.on('willInsertElement'),

  hide: function() {
    this.$().fadeOut(this.get('controller.duration'));
  }

});
```

And then in the controller:

```
Em.ObjectController.extend(
  Em.Evented, { // Important mixin!

  duration: 500,

  actions: {
    removeSomeChildView: function() {
      this.trigger('closeChildView');

      Em.run.later(this, function() {
        // Then do the stuff to destroy the view here.
      }, this.get('duration'));
    }
  }

});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `this.removeFromParent()` method in the view to consolidate the hiding and removing of the view.

If the destruction is actually started in the view itself, you could use these same principles before you call the destroy method and use `.on('willDestroyElement')` to send an action to the controller or route should you need a callback after the view has been removed.

Pre-destroy animation can be done in the same way by running `this.$().hide` on `didInsertElement` and then using a `show()` method to transition the view element.

### Aligning JS and CSS transition times

If you doing some of all of  your transitions in CSS you'll want to make sure the transition times between the CSS and JS are aligned. This is pretty simple. In your view, make sure the CSS transition takes place on the view's element and then:

```
SomeView = Em.View.extend({
  transitionDuration: Em.computed.alias('controller.transitionDuration'),

  setTransitionDuration: function() {
    var ms = parseFloat(this.$().css('transition-duration')) * 1000; // In milliseconds

    if (ms) {
      this.set('transitionTime', ms);
    }
  }.on('didInsertElement'),
});
```

This will update the transition duration on your view and controller to match whatever you write in your CSS. Whatever value you specify for `transitionDuration` on the controller is the fallback value for `transitionDuration` and you could add an `if ()` in the above method should you want to do some validating before overriding the default JS `transitionDuration`.