# Adding Animations to views created and destroyed via the handlebars if helper

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a view like this:

```
{{#if someCondition}}
  {{view view.someView}}
{{/if}}
```

When the someCondition is true, the view inside will be created and when it is false it will be destroyed if it has been created.

Has anyone come up with a way of adding animations?  This is especially difficult when the condition is false and the view is simply nuked.

Paul

Comment: I had the same issue a month ago, still haven't found a perfect solution.  Here's my SO question and how I'm currently handling it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092632/animating-views-before-destruction-in-emberjs.  If you find a more elegant way, please don't hesitate to share :)